# Implementing search box in my Java program

Tags: java

I am making simple browser. I want to implement a search box which will automatically redirect to the results of search for example in http://uk.ask.com/ it looks quite simple.

If I was going to search for "hello SO" it link would look like this.

`http://uk.ask.com/web?qsrc=1&o=0&l=dir&q=hello+SO+&dm=all`

So what I am wanting to do is make a JTextField where user can enter what he is searching for, and then just fill in whatever he typed into the url

`http://uk.ask.com/web?qsrc=1&o=0&l=dir&q="FILL HERE WITH + instead of spaces           "&dm=all`

I don't know how to split the string entered and fill the spaces with + signs. Any idea ?
Also this is just the way I thought it would be possible to do it. I would much appreciate any other suggestions. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [URL encode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) the string.

Comment: Okay I like this idea, so I would pass this search string into this class and return new converted string ? am i getting this right ?

Comment: @Tom: Exactly.  Use the `UTF-8` encoding.

Comment: You should pass `"UTF-8"` as the encoding.

Comment: Ha thanks I was like "WHY IS THERE ERROR IN THERE" then i realized i need to throw UnsupportedEncodingException >.< derp... Thank you anyway! Works perfect ^^ much appreciate it thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
url.replace(" ", "+");
```

Comment: That will break for searches like `50% off`.